# Ctrl+T used to work in chrome but no longer works

Tags: google-chrome

Seems to be a google account issue. This is across computers when I log into my google account on chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you can no longer open Tabs with Ctrl-T ?

Comment: Which OS, Chrome version ? Does it work in Incognito mode ?

Comment: Yes Ctrl+T no longer works on both Windows 7 and 10. Ctrl+Shift+T works pretty well.

Comment: @DL Narasimhan same thing happening to me now, did you figure out what was going on?

Comment: @boardtc it was one of the extensions I'd downloaded. Just try disabling any of the recently added extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your dropdown of your menu.  I'm guessing Ctrl-T is still there.  Maybe your control key is out.  Try the other Control Key.  Either that or maybe you have other software that is capturing/masking the key before the browser can register it thus stopping the browser for opening a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off function (Fn) toggle. Uninstall/reinstall Chrome or try restoring Chrome to default settings.The fix for me was I had created a key binding in VLC Player as ctrl + t, and once I closed the program, the issue was gone and I could make new tabs again.